# Intermittent "error occurred while making the HTTP request"

Tags: httpclient, antivirus

*error occurred while making the HTTP request*

I have a c# client that calls a remote endpoint using a HttpClient.  The client is hosted on a Windows Server.

The client will run fine for a long time and then I encounter a "error occurred while making the HTTP request".

We do use Trend Micro AntiVirus.

I run this client about every 5 minutes.  It works very well when it starts but when the error happens it keeps happening.  To resolve it I shut the service down, wait awhile and then restart it.

Here is my code snippet:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 10000;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);
}
```

Here is the error:

Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful it you could include what language your code is in, and the details of the HTTP error you get, such as the HTTP error code, and the headers of the response.

Comment: Thank you, Douglas.  I have edited my question to add more information.  Thanks again!